# Blazor WASM calling Web API Core method to get the windows user name

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor applications. My scenario is, I have to get back the Windows logged user name from the hosted Blazor WASM application on IIS.

Below are the steps I followed.

1. Created a ASP.Net Web API Core project and decorated it with  [ApiController]. In the launchsettings.json file changed the following attributes.

"windowsAuthentication": true,

"anonymousAuthentication": false,

2. Enabled Windows and disabled Anonymous authentication in the IIS where my Web API is hosted.
3. In the Startup.cs file of the WebAPI configured the below

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

4. In the controller method, added a property

   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

and initialized it in the constructor as below.

```
public UsersController(IUsersRepository usersRepository,

        IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)

    {            _usersRepository = usersRepository;

            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;

            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    }
```

5. Finally in the API method

   [HttpGet("getusername")]
   public string GetUserByName()

   ```
     {
            var principal=_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

            return  principal.Identity.Name;
    }
   ```

When I browse the above Web API from IIS and call the above API method, I get the proper user name with domain/username.

Everything looks good so far, the actual issue is with the Blazor Webassembly project which invokes the above Web API method. When the Blazor WASM is hosted on the IIS( the same server as the above Web API) and calls the API method to get the user name I always get a null value. I made similar changes as Web API to launchsettings.json file and in IIS Authentication( Enabled Windows and disabled Anonymous authentication) in Blazor WASM.

I am invoking the API as below

```
public async Task<string> GetUserName()
    {
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<string>
            (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/users/getusername"), new 
        JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });            
    }
```

Since this is going to be a intranet site, we did not want to do any authentication by having the user to login through a Login page. The site address is set to auto login in the Chrome browser settings.

Could you guide me in the right direction, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: As it moving to `intranet` and there is not interactive login functionality if the user already not logged in I doubt there is any option to get that user's information or machine information either.

Comment: Yes, its an Intranet application and we do not want the user to login again with a customized login page when the browser launches. Seems I am missing some link as to why its getting so difficult to get the user's information. When the Web API is returning the username when hosted on IIS, why cant the Blazor WASM which invokes this Web API return me the users info.